# Is there an SE site for finding a particular book when only the premise is known?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There is a short story that I read years ago that I am trying to find. However, I only remember the premise; I don't recall the author or title. Is there any SE site where I could post a story premise to see if anyone knows what it is?

Answer (score 3):

If its genre is science fiction or fantasy, it may be on topic at [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) using their [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) tag. If it is anime-related in some way, it may be on topic at [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) using their [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idenfication-request) tag.

Other than that, I don't think there are any SE sites that allow questions like this for books.

Comment: [Lets Play The Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) had story-identification as its 2nd most popular tag, but with a star: "and when your site’s most popular tag is “book-recommendation”, there are perhaps deeper problems to contend with." - that site [failed its beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6426/literature).

Comment: @MichaelT Yep, and the identification tags are still top at [scifi.se] and [anime.se] and second at [movies.se]. Sigh.

Comment: Looks like the former literature SE site would have been perfect. I think the story is a classic, so I'm going to try the Literature Network forums.